# body event not triggering

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onclick="myFunction(event)">

<p onclick="myFunction(event)">Click on a paragraph. An alert box will alert the element that triggered the event.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The target property returns the element that triggered the event, and not necessarily the eventlistener's element.</p>

<script>
function myFunction(event) { 
    alert(event.target.nodeName);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So when I click on `<p>`, there are two pop-up windows which are all regarding to P, but shouldn't we have one P and one Body as onclick event is associated with `<body>` tag?

Comment: Read [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) and http://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 1):

You code working correct .Its showing target element tag name .Its right because you not clicking  empty body .its have some children element That was `p` so its showing the `p` .it only show the clicked text of element tag name .simply add a text not contain any element direct text of the body.

```js
function myFunction(event) { 
    alert(event.target.nodeName);
}
```

```html
<body onclick="myFunction(event)">
its direct text of the body click here you get the body
<p onclick="myFunction(event)">Click on a paragraph. An alert box will alert the element that triggered the event.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The target property returns the element that triggered the event, and not necessarily the eventlistener's element.</p>


</body>
```